# How to supress errors for missing file in while loop

Tags: bash

For example, here's part of my bash script:

```
while read line
do
    [some stuff]
done < $group.$project.$branch.notready.txt
```

But, during the course of the loop, whether this one or whether this loop is within another loop, the name of the file can change from notready to ready.  When that happens, I get no such file or directory error.  It's fine if the file is not there for the sake of the script, but is there a way to suppress the error?

I've tried:

```
while read line 2>/dev/null
```

but that don't work.

Edit:  this may be an easier way to replicate

```
while read line
do
    echo "$line"
done < random.file.dont.exist.txt
```

Comment: I was unable to reproduce your problem. Could you make a simple example: I tried something like this: `while read line; do echo $line; rm ~/foo; done < ~/foo`

Comment: The easiest might be to add at the end of the loop something like `[ -r $group.$project.$branch.notready.txt ] || break` to break out of the loop if the file does not exist anymore.

Comment: I also believe the error comes from another place in the loop.

Comment: this replicates it:   while read line; do echo $line; done < random.nonexistant.file.txt

Comment: It should be fine if the file name is changed *during the course of the loop*, because `<` only opens the file once.  You have a problem if the file name is changed *before the start of the loop*.

Comment: @TobySpeight yes.  I change the filename before the start of the loop.  This is intentional in my script.  The error doesn't impact the script at all.  I would just like to suppress the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you wrap the whole `while` statement in braces it works, but note that this will supress *any* error messages from any part of the loop:

```
{
    while read line; do
        echo "$line"
    done < random.file.dont.exist.txt
} 2>/dev/null
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for.  I understand it suppresses everything, and for my script, that is alright.

Answer (score 3):

Consider breaking the open operation away from the loop itself, so you can process its errors separately:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
case $BASH_VERSION in ''|[1-3].*|4.[012].*) echo "ERROR: Bash 4.3+ needed" >&2; exit 1;; esac
if { exec {input_fd}<possibly_existing_file; } 2>/dev/null; then
  while IFS= read -r line <&$input_fd; do
    echo "Read line $line from possibly_existing_file"
  done
  exec {input_fd}<&- # close input file
else
  echo "possibly_existing_file does not exist yet or otherwise could not be opened" >&2
fi
```

`exec {input_fd}<filename` is bash 4.3's *automatic file descriptor assignment* support, which picks an open file descriptor number and puts it in the variable `input_fd`. On shells new enough to have this support, you can also use `exec {input_fd}<&-` to close a file, or `<&$fd_var` to redirect to a FD number found in a variable.

Comment: For me, this would be too much for what I'm doing.  but it's good to know.

Comment: Very nice feature of of bash 4.3. I was unaware of it. The usage of the extra If, is a bit cumbersome. I would suggest to test the redirection, and if it fails, set it to `/dev/null`. The loop can still be executed, and the branch is not there (i.e. it is hidden in the fd)

Comment: Personally, I'd call the `if` a feature, not a bug -- it makes it explicit that one can detect and handle the case with whatever special application-specific logic is called for.

Comment: I was not referring to the if as a bug ;-)

Answer (score 1):

We can separate the opening of the stream from the use of it, like this (assuming we're using only the standard streams so far):

```
exec 3<"$file" &&
while read line
do echo "$line"
done <&3
exec 3<&-
```

On its own, that still doesn't suppress the message, but we can redirect standard error while we `exec`, and restore it afterwards.  It looks a bit messy, but does the job:

```
exec 4>&2 2>/dev/null 3<"$file" 2>&4 4>&- &&
while read line <&3
do
    echo "$line"
done
exec 3<&-
```

Broken down, the `exec` line:

1. Duplicates standard error onto stream 4, saving it for later.
2. Sends standard error to the null device.
3. Opens our input file on descriptor 3.
4. Restores standard error from 4 where we saved it.
5. Closes the unused stream 4.

If those steps succeeded, then we perform the `while` loop (and the usual streams are restored, so errors within the loop will go to the error stream as usual).

We have to jump through the hoop of saving and restoring the error stream, because there's no way to redirect the output of `exec` - its changes are permanent.

### Addendum

As shown in [another answer](/a/60174246/4850040), we *can* redirect the error message alone, without the jumping through hoops (and skip closing if the open fails):

```
{ exec 3<"$file"; } 2>/dev/null &&
{
    while read line <&3
    do
        echo "$line" >&2
    done
    exec 3<&-
}
```

Comment: Hmm. I note that in the addendum, we're doing the `exec 3<&-` unconditionally, such that it runs even if the `exec 3<"$file"` failed.

Comment: @Charles, I originally had `&&` between the `done` and the close, but then realised that the loop could return false for other reasons.  It's still safe to close stream 3 if we failed to open it; it's just untidy.  I suppose we could group the `while` and `exec` in `{ }` as well.  Actually, yes, I'll make that edit.

Comment: Actually, it would be nice if there was a simpler way to carry the exit status of the `while`, without the `exec 3<&-` resetting it.  If we want to retain that, we find ourselves needing to save a copy of `$?` which is ugly.

Comment: I think the code you have right now is pretty clean, though personally I'd put the `{` opening the latter block immediately after the `&&`.

Answer (score 1):

There is more to this question that meets the eye:

> **The OP states:** But, during the course of the loop, whether this one or whether this loop is within another loop, the name of the file can change from notready to ready. When that happens, I get no such file or directory error.

The questions that need to be asked here are:

1. What is the origin of the error? *Creating an input redirection with a non-existing file.*
2. What happens to the loop if the file is renamed or removed? *Nothing, it has no influence on the loop*.
3. How can I cleanly solve this? *With a clean validation check (see below)*.

**1. Origin of the error:**

The error which is encountered in the OP is an error created by bash itself by attempting to create an input redirection with a non-existing file. It has nothing to do with the while-loop presented in the OP.

```
$ cat - < "$(mktemp -u)"
bash: /tmp/tmp.qynPrg8Mst: No such file or directory
```

**2. What happens to the while-loop if the input is removed/renamed?**

Assume the following execution:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
fname="$(mktemp)"
seq 1 2 > "$fname"
while read -r line; do
   echo "$line"
   [ -r "$fname" ] && rm "$fname" && ls -l /proc/$$/fd
done < "$fname"
```

This process:

1. creates a temporary file containing 2 lines
2. uses a while loop to read the file line by line
3. on the first loop-cycle, it deletes the input file and prints the file descriptors of the running process

```
$ ./test.sh 
1
total 0
lr-x------ 1 user group 64 Feb 12 14:52 0 -> /tmp/tmp.6oTtotu6Xr (deleted)
l-wx------ 1 user group 64 Feb 12 14:52 1 -> /dev/pts/46
lrwx------ 1 user group 64 Feb 12 14:52 10 -> /dev/pts/46
lrwx------ 1 user group 64 Feb 12 14:52 2 -> /dev/pts/46
lr-x------ 1 user group 64 Feb 12 14:52 255 -> /home/user/tmp/test.sh
2
```

What you notice is that, even though the file is deleted in the second cycle, it can still read it. The corresponding file descriptor (`0`), on the other hand, still exists but is marked as deleted. The reason for this is given in [[ServerFault] What happens to a deleted file still subject to redirection on linux?](https://serverfault.com/q/74321)

> If a program still has a file handle open, the file continues to exist. It disappears from your directory listings and looks gone but until the last file handle is closed the file continues to grow.

When we rename the file, nothing happens, as only the filename changed. The file descriptor will point to the new name of the file, but this is located on the same inode of the disk.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
fname="$(mktemp)"
fname2="$(mktemp)"
echo "$fname $fname2"
seq 1 2 > "$fname"
while read -r line; do
   echo "$line"
   [ -r "$fname" ] && mv "$fname" "$fname2" && ls -l /proc/$$/fd
done < "$fname"
```

which outputs:

```
/tmp/tmp.3AYt84IJDW /tmp/tmp.JQJGAsUuBz
1
total 0
lr-x------ 1 user group 64 Feb 12 15:01 0 -> /tmp/tmp.JQJGAsUuBz
l-wx------ 1 user group 64 Feb 12 15:01 1 -> /dev/pts/46
lrwx------ 1 user group 64 Feb 12 15:01 10 -> /dev/pts/46
lrwx------ 1 user group 64 Feb 12 15:01 2 -> /dev/pts/46
lr-x------ 1 user group 64 Feb 12 15:01 255 -> /home/user/tmp/test.sh
2
```

**3. What does this mean for the OP?**

The two cases above demonstrate that deleting or renaming a file which is used as stdin in a process, here the while-loop, has no effect on the correct execution of the loop. The error only comes from creating the input redirection with a non-existing file. A possible way, for the OP, would be

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
fname="/path/to/input/"
while read -r line
    echo "$line"
done < "$( [ -r "$fname" ] && echo "$fname" || echo "/dev/null" )"
```

This, however, still makes it possible, but less likely, that the input file `$fname` is altered at the time of creating the input redirection.

The safest way would be:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
fname="/path/to/input"
{ exec 3< "$fname"; } 2> /dev/null || { exec 3< /dev/null; }
while read -r -u 3 line
    echo "$line"
done
exec 3>&-
```

The above essentially sets file descriptor 3 to the input file, but if it does not exists, points it to `/dev/null`. Then it performs the loop with `/dev/null`

When you have, as mentioned in the OP, this loop into another loop, you might do:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
fname="/path/to/input"
for i in 1 2; do
   { exec 3< "$fname"; } 2> /dev/null || break
   while read -r -u 3 line
      echo "$line"
   done
   exec 3>&-
done
```

---

**Useful links:**

https://wiki.bash-hackers.org/howto/redirection_tutorial

Comment: @CharlesDuffy  Ah indeed, totally correct! I believe I fixed both cases now. Thanks